# How can I programatically open the “compose” Box in GMail using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I am creating a script for Gmail, which open Single compose Box in the Gmail page like when click on compose button. I have tried the following code but sometimes it opens multiple compose Boxes.
But I want to open only one compose box when script will run. Is there any other way to open Compose Box.

```
        var down = new MouseEvent('mousedown');
        var up = new MouseEvent('mouseup');
        var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("T-I-KE")[0];
        elem.dispatchEvent(down);
        elem.dispatchEvent(up);
```

[Compose Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FhAE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could be more robust and only dispatch the mouse events if the compose frame is not showing. The following seems to work for me.

```
var composeButton = document.getElementsByClassName("T-I-KE")[0];    
var down = new MouseEvent('mousedown');
var up = new MouseEvent('mouseup');

function openCompose() {
    if (document.querySelectorAll('.dw.np').length) {
        composeButton.dispatchEvent(down);
        composeButton.dispatchEvent(up);
    }
}

openCompose();
```

Comment: Is there any option we can do without using MouseEvent, like directly calling some javascript function ?